# All of functionality is running , but if this code is on console command execute(), is not working

Tags: configuration, magento2.4, command-line

I am looking for magento 2 developer.
I need to build a extension that clear the cart every day by cron job.
So I made the extension for this work. all of the functionality is OK on testing mode

- I made testing controller to clear cart. this is ok.
- Also cron module is OK
- command testing module is OK

But just when clearing cart function execute on cron or command, this function is not working.

```
   public function execute()
    {
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $allItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }
}
```

this code is for controller. this functionality is running

```
protected function execute(
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    ) {
        $output->writeln("Clear cart from cmd: start");

    }
```

this code is for command. printed "Clear cart from cmd: start" message

But when execute below code, this function is not running

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $allItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
        }
```

like

```
    protected function execute(
        InputInterface $input,
        OutputInterface $output
    ) {
        $this->_appState->setAreaCode('frontend');
        $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
        $cart = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart');
        $allItems = $cart->getQuote()->getAllVisibleItems();
        foreach ($allItems as $item) {
            $itemId = $item->getItemId();
            $cart->removeItem($itemId)->save();
            $output->writeln("Clear cart from cmd: start2");
        }
    }
```

How can I run this function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code will only delete quote of the current user. So it might be work with controller, but not in cron and cmd.

If you want to clear full cart of every user everyday then you should load all active quotes and delete them.

Please try below code. You can add date filter and other as well in quote collection.

```
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$quotes = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter("is_active",1);
foreach ($quotes as $quote) {
    $quote->delete();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`\Magento\Checkout\Model\Cart` works when a user/customer on web browsers.

If you want to remove an item from the cart  then you can use

`\Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface::deleteById`

If you want to  remove the quote/cart  fully  then you can use `\Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface::delete`

### Example:

```
<?php

namespace StackExchange\MagentoModule\Console\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\CartItemRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\CartInterface;

class ClearCart extends Command
{
    /**
     * @var CartRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $cartRepository;
    /**
     * @var CartItemRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $itemRepository;
    /**
     * @var SearchCriteriaBuilder
     */
    private $searchCriteriaBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        CartRepositoryInterface $cartRepository,
        CartItemRepositoryInterface $itemRepository,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        string $name = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($name);
        $this->cartRepository = $cartRepository;
        $this->itemRepository = $itemRepository;
        $this->searchCriteriaBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritDoc
     */
    protected function configure()
    {
        // Add Own Command line
        $this->setName('stackExchanges:clear:cart');
        $this->setDescription('Clear Cart');
        parent::configure();
    }

    /**
     * CLI command description
     *
     * @param InputInterface $input
     * @param OutputInterface $output
     *
     * @return void
     */
    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): void
    {

        // Solution1: Remove all Quote/Cart from Database

        $quotesResult = $this->cartRepository->getList(
            $this->searchCriteriaBuilder->addFilter(
                CartInterface::KEY_ENTITY_ID,
                0,
                'gt'
            )->create()
        );
        if ($quotesResult->getTotalCount() > 0){
            foreach ($quotesResult->getItems() as $quote){
                // Remove quote
                $this->cartRepository->delete($quote);
            }
        }
        
        // Solution2: when you have a quote/ cart iD
        $cartId = 10;
        try{
            $sinGleQuote = $this->cartRepository->get($cartId);
            $this->cartRepository->delete($sinGleQuote);
        }catch (\Exception $exception){
            
        }
        
        
    }
}
```